# Web scraping: finding all contents when specific part of HTML is changing repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, selenium

In [this](http://dynamic.pulselive.com/dynamic/cricinfo/graphing/index.html?cgid=71069) website, we can see that the description below the graph ( like:*"Mohammad Nawaz to Eoin Morgan, 55.0 mph, dot ball."*) is changing repeatedly. 
I want to scrape all the description about the trajectories.
 In HTML, the specific part about the description is:

```
<div class="trajDescription" id="traj-description" classname="trajDescription">
<b>34.3</b> 
Mohammad Nawaz to Eoin Morgan, 55.0 mph, dot ball.
</div>
```

When I use **selenium** to locate the element and want to get the text:

```
traj_description = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#traj-description')
print(traj_description.text)
```

the result I get is always just one sentence. like:

```
40.1 Chris Woakes to Sarfraz Ahmed, 84.2 mph, 1 run, hit straight down the ground.
```

Is there any methods to get all the descriptions? For example:

```
Mohammad Nawaz to Eoin Morgan, 55.0 mph, dot ball.
Mohammad Nawaz to Eoin Morgan, 45.0 mph, down to the ground.
Chris Woakes to Sarfraz Ahmed, 84.2 mph, 1 run, hit straight down the ground
```

Comment: Probably not since all that content doesn't exist in the DOM at the same time. It's being changed dynamically via JS it looks like. You are just getting the initial value.

Comment: Where is your code that attempts to do this? The code you posted is only going to print the first instance of text.

Comment: It will work just fine... you just have to write code that waits for the text to change, pulls the text, and stores it/writes it as you want.

Answer (score -1):

every second,get a new '`driver`' again, instead of using the existing `driver`

Comment: This won't work because that just launches a new browser and orphans the previous one.